# Python regex error : TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, regex

New to python. Like to pre-process some data and join them afterwords, the function which takes one string as input and the output is a single string preprocessed

```
def message_to_words(message ):
        letters = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", message ) 
        words = letters.lower().split()                             
        stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))                  
        meaningful_words = [w for w in words if not w in stops]  
        return( " ".join( meaningful_words ))
```

When I call the function

```
clean_messages = []
for i in xrange(0, df["Message"].size):
        clean_messages.append( message_to_words( df["Message"][i] ) )
```

I get this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-156-061399cb4dfd> in <module>()
      3 for i in xrange(0, df["Message"].size):
----> 5         clean_messages.append( message_to_words( df["Message"][i] ) )

---> 12     letters = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", message )
..../python2.7/re.pyc in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    153     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    154     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 155     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    156 
    157 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

When the data rows is within 500 "print df["Message"][i]" is a string and the code has no errors, however, when the data rows is increased above 500 "print df["Message"][i]" is a float. Got me puzzled

Comment: What is `stopwords` in code above? in statement `stops = set(stopwords.words("english"))`

Comment: The error means that df["Message"][i] has to be a string or buffer. Can you please check the type of df["Message"][i] by print type(df["Message"][i])?

Comment: stopwords is the stopword list from Python nltk

Comment: print df["Message"][i] and it is a float, while actually it is meant to be a string

Comment: solved the problem by passing ( str( df["Message"][i] )),thanks